# Practsing dart with build projects

Tags: dart, project

I just finsh dart cours ( the baseic and oop), and now i want resources to practsing dart with build projects, if any one know a youtube channal, web site, or book that can help me build projects with dart pleas tell me about it

Comment: Opinion based. voting to close. have a look at this repo btw https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.